# How to create a venn diagram where sections are colored by the values of a continuous variable (like a heat map)?

Tags: r, colors, heatmap, venn-diagram

I'd like to create a Venn diagram in R, where the sections are colored based on the value of a continuous variable.  Each venn diagram section has its own value (ranging from 0-1), and this value is DIFFERENT than the count variable also displayed in the diagram.  I have three categories (and all of their intersections) to display (a total of 7 values for the continuous variable).

Does ggVennDiagram allow for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the euler function with fills defined as you wish.  Here is an example with colors, but you could use a gray scale.

```
col<- c("red","blue","green","yellow","purple","black","white")
test <- plot(euler(c("A"=79,"B"=378,"C"=134, "A&C" = 55, "A&B" = 176, 
                     "B&C" = 110, "A&B&SC" = 101)),quantities = TRUE, 
fills= col);
```